# Script to sum columns in multiple files

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

```
File A
Sector A    100
Sector B    200
Sector C    300
Sector D    500


File B
Sector A    100
Sector B    200
Sector C    300
Sector D    500


File C
Sector A    100
Sector B    200
Sector C    300
Sector D    500
```

I would like to get single file that has the sum of sector A,B,C of all files.

Final Result

```
Sector A    300
Sector B    600
Sector C    900
Sector D    1500
```

Shell scripting would be great!!! you suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried?
PS: maybe you meant "Sector D 1500"

Comment: If one of the answers here resolved your question please accept that answer. Accepting an answer closes this questions and rewards the author of the accepted answer. If your question was not resolved consider explaining why.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{a[$1 FS $2]+=$NF} END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' fileA fileB fileC
```

Output will be as follows.

```
Sector A 300
Sector B 600
Sector C 900
Sector D 1500
```

Comment: Hello Ravinder,

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. i am new to scripting, so could you please write up the steps. This will help learn faster. Also, i have multiple files, can i use wild card (*) at the end of the command

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your columns are delimited by tabs you can use GNU datamash:

```
sort fileA fileB fileC | datamash groupby 1 sum 2
```

Output

```
Sector A    300
Sector B    600
Sector C    900
Sector D    1500
```

If your (possibly large) individual input files are already sorted you can speed up the process using `sort -m ...` instead of `sort`.

Comment: Add `-W` if they're separated by arbitrary whitespace.

Comment: @Shawn Unfortunately it isn't that easy. `Sector A` contains a whitespace too. If you know that the first column always contains exactly one space (as for OP's example input) then we can use `datamash -W groupby 1,2 sum 3`. If the first "column" can be anything, then we are lost, but that is a general problem *not* specific to `datamash`.

Answer (score 0):

Not the smartest solution but quite simple and comprehensible :

```
for f in fileA fileB fileC
do
   while read line
   do
   A=$(echo $line | grep "Sector A" | tr -s " "| cut -d' ' -f3)
   B=$(echo $line | grep "Sector B" | tr -s " "| cut -d' ' -f3)
   C=$(echo $line | grep "Sector C" | tr -s " "| cut -d' ' -f3)
   D=$(echo $line | grep "Sector D" | tr -s " "| cut -d' ' -f3)
   secA=$((secA+A))
   secB=$((secB+B))
   secC=$((secC+C))
   secD=$((secD+D))
   done < $f
done
echo "Sector A" $secA
echo "Sector B" $secB
echo "Sector C" $secC
echo "Sector D" $secD
```

Answer (score 0):

**1**.`sort` assisted `awk`

```
$  sort filea.txt fileb.txt  filec.txt | awk ' { c=$2; if(c!=p && NR>1 ) { print $1,p,s;s=0} p=c;s+=$3 } END { print $1,p,s } '
Sector A 300
Sector B 600
Sector C 900
Sector D 1500
$
```

**2.**`paste` assisted `awk`

```
$ paste filea.txt fileb.txt  filec.txt | awk ' { for(i=3;i<=NF;i+=3) s+=$i; print $1,$2,s ; s=0 } '
Sector A 300
Sector B 600
Sector C 900
Sector D 1500
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl,

```
$ perl -0777 -ne ' s/^(.+) (\d+)$/$kv{$1}+=$2/gme; END { for(sort keys %kv) { print "$_ $kv{$_}\n" }} ' filea.txt fileb.txt  filec.txt
Sector A    300
Sector B    600
Sector C    900
Sector D    1500
$
```